# haw i can adapt dhtmlxGantt display screen with my component?

Tags: css, laravel, components

i use dhtmlxGantt because i need gantt diagram in my project but i have a desplay problem . i use vuejs component that's why i put the code of dhtmlxGantt in my component but the display isn't clear 
this is my code :
//Gantt component

```
    <template>
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">


                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div id="gantt_here">

                    </div>
                    </div>

             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        created(){
       gantt.init("gantt_here");
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
body{
    margin: 10px ;
}
</style>
```

and i call this two file

```
    <script src="https://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

please i need help

Answer (score 0):

VueJS is very complicated when it comes to javascript components external to the components, what I can advise you in this case is to do the internal import of the component's library and try to use it, as I never used this component, so I don't know if it uses jQuery, but there are ways to use [jQuery in VueJS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).
An example of how you would use it would be installing the library using the command `npm install --save @types/dhtmlxgantt`, and importing it into your component.

```
<script>
import gantt from '@types/dhtmlxgantt'

export default {
  ...
  created() {
    gantt.init("gantt_here");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: please are you sure about this command npm install --save @types/dhtmlxgantt ?

Comment: Yes, it is what shows the use of npm : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dhtmlxgantt